# VB WPF application crashing when running Dev Express Scheduler form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, devexpress-wpf

I've developed an application which contains a form and that form contains a Dev Express Scheduler. On my Dev machine, when I run the application, the application runs fine. When I run the same application of a different computer, I get the following message:

I've managed to get the Window Logs which shows the following:

```
Application: AGEstateAgentsTenancyManagementSystem.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at AGEstateAgentsTenancyManagementSystem.frmMainWindow.menuItemCalendarScheduler_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at AGEstateAgentsTenancyManagementSystem.Application.Main()
```

I've tried several rebuilds but all attempts have failed.

Does anyone know or experience this issue before?

menuItemCalendarScheduler_Click Content:

```
Private Sub menuItemCalendarScheduler_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'Load the general mesage form.
    Dim frmGeneralMessage As New frmGeneralMessage
    frmGeneralMessage.lblGeneralMessage.Content = "Loading Scheduler / Calendar" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                                                  "Please wait..."
    frmGeneralMessage.Show()

    'Load the calendar scheduler form.
    Dim frmScheduler As New frmScheduler
    frmScheduler.Show()

    'Closes the general message form.
    frmGeneralMessage.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include the content of the menuItemCalendarScheduler_Click method?

Comment: Hi Dan, I've updated the question above which shows the Code the menu item contains.